# How can I append objects to the body of a component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to set up some functionality on this React component so that a user can add and remove empty radio button options to a page that a user can type text into. The only issue that I am having is that I am relatively new to React and am not 100% how to do this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class TextRadio extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        state = {
            textValue: ""
        }

    };

    handleInputChange = event => {
        const value = event.target.value;
        const name = event.target.name;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }

    addBox = () => {

    }

    removeBox = () => {

    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="form-check">
                    <input className="form-check-input" type="radio" id="" name="" value="" />
                    <label className="form-check-label" for="">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" />
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-check">
                    <input className="form-check-input" type="radio" id="option" name="option" value="option" />
                    <label className="form-check-label" for="option">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" />
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-check">
                    <input className="form-check-input" type="radio" id="option" name="option" value="option" />
                    <label className="form-check-label" for="option">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" />
                    </label>
                </div>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.addBox}>
                    Add Option
                </button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.removeBox}>
                    Remove Option
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TextRadio;
```

The result that I am expecting to happen is to have it so the component can add and remove radio button options from the page depending on the button that the user presses

Comment: Will need an array of objects you can map in your render() method and you would modify that array in your state to add/remove/edit. Note that element id can't be repeated in a page. Also  doesn't make sense having same value for 2 radios with same name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was completed just your `addBox` and `RemoveBox` functions, i hope that's help you

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class TextRadio extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      radioButtons: []
    };
  }

  handleInputChange = event => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    const name = event.target.name;
  };

  addBox = () => {
    this.setState(prevstate => {
      let radioButtons = prevstate.radioButtons;
      if (radioButtons.length === 0) {
        radioButtons.push({
          id: 1,
          name: "radiobutton",
          value: "test"
        });
        return {
          radioButtons: radioButtons
        };
      } else {
        radioButtons.push({
          id: radioButtons[radioButtons.length - 1].id + 1,
          name: "raiodButton_" + (radioButtons[radioButtons.length - 1].id + 1),
          value: radioButtons[radioButtons.length - 1].value
        });
        return {
          radioButtons: radioButtons
        };
      }
    });
  };

  removeBox = () => {
    this.setState(prevstate => {
      let radioButtons = prevstate.radioButtons;
      if (radioButtons.length !== 0) {
        radioButtons.pop(radioButtons[radioButtons.length - 1]);
        return {
          radioButtons: radioButtons
        };
      } else {
        return { radioButtons: radioButtons };
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="form-check">
          {this.state.radioButtons.map(radiobutton => {
            return (
              <div>
                <input
                  className="form-check-input"
                  type="radio"
                  id={radiobutton.id}
                  name={radiobutton.name}
                  value={radiobutton.value}
                />
                <label className="form-check-label" for="">
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" />
                </label>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.addBox}>
          Add Option
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-danger"
          onClick={this.removeBox}
        >
          Remove Option
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TextRadio;
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/confident-browser-tmojp

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around with your idea and made some changes in the code, just to show you an example, how you can dynamically create new components and store them in applications state and then render out to user based on their actions.

I created new component just for form UI: option, input field and remove button. If user clicks on the Add Option, new item of the component is added to application state and then render out. Remove button is used to remove Item from state.

```
class TextRadio extends Component {
  state = {
    optionInputs: []
  };

  addBox = () => {
    const optionInputsUpdated = [
      ...this.state.optionInputs,
      <OptionInput id={uuid.v4()} remove={this.removeBox} />
    ];
    this.setState({ optionInputs: optionInputsUpdated });
  };

  removeBox = id => {
    const optionInputsUpdated = this.state.optionInputs.filter(
      item => item.props.id !== id
    );
    this.setState({ optionInputs: optionInputsUpdated });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.optionInputs.map((optionInput, idx) => {
          return (
            <div key={idx} test="123">
              {optionInput}
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.addBox}>
          Add Option
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const OptionInput = props => {
  return (
    <div className="form-check">
      <input
        className="form-check-input"
        type="radio"
        id=""
        name="radio"
        value=""
      />
      <label className="form-check-label" for="">
        <input className="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" />
      </label>{" "}
      <button
        type="button"
        className="btn btn-danger"
        onClick={() => props.remove(props.id)}
      >
        Remove Option
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Hope this gives you better understanding, how to achieve your goal.

If you need additional help, just post a comment under this answer, and I will update demo to help you.

Here is DEMO I created from your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-ganguly-s4wls

Answer (score 0):

first you have to initialize an empty array state

```
this.state={
  radioButtons : [{input:''}]
}
```

then in your return statement you have to loop through the radioButtons array and show the radio button with input

```
{
  this.state.radioButtons.map(item => (
    <div className="form-check">
        <input className="form-check-input" type="radio" id="option" name="option" value="option" />
        <label className="form-check-label" for="option">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" />
        </label>
    </div>
  ))
}
```

then in your addBox function append an  object on every click

```
      addBox = () => {
        this.setState({radioButtons:[...this.state.radioButtons, {input:''}]})
}
```

function to remove a radio button object

```
  removeBox = () => {
    let radioArray = this.state.radioButtons
    radioArray.pop()
    this.setState({radioButtons:radioArray})
  }
```

**Final code Looks like this :**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      radioButtons :[{input:''}]
    }
  }

  addBox = () => {
    this.setState({radioButtons:[...this.state.radioButtons, {input:''}]})

  }
  removeBox = () => {
    let radioArray = this.state.radioButtons
    radioArray.pop()
    this.setState({radioButtons:radioArray})
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
              {
      this.state.radioButtons.map(item => (
        <div className="form-check">
            <input className="form-check-input" type="radio" id="option" name="option" value="option" />
            <label className="form-check-label" for="option">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" />
            </label>
        </div>
      ))
    }
               <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.addBox}>
                    Add Option
                </button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.removeBox}>
                    Remove Option
                </button>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[codepen Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-lederberg-35vwc)